# making the bootstrap container size bigger makes the page unresponsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I need to make the container size of bootstrap bigger. I put this stylesheet  to make the container size bigger:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
        .container.max-width-940 {
            max-width: 1390px !important;
        }
    }

 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .container.max-width-940 {
            max-width: 1390px !important;
        }
    }

.container.max-width-940

{
    min-width: 1390px !important;
}
```

and used it in my div tag on my page:

```
<div  style="background-color:white;border-radius:10px;align-content:center;align-self:center;vertical-align:middle;width:100%" class="container max-width-940 body-content" />
```

whenever I do that, the page becomes unresponsive. whenever I resize the page, controls and text start coming beyond the screen. Below is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  



    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
            .navbar-brand {    
    display: flex;
    white-space: normal;
    }
            @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container.max-width-940 {
        max-width: 1390px !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container.max-width-940 {
        max-width: 1390px !important;
    }
}

.container.max-width-940 {
    min-width: 1390px !important;
}

    </style>

</head>
<body style="background-color:cadetblue">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="s" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
 <nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #264653; position:absolute; top:0px; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%); width:90%; ">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <span class="navbar-brand" style="display:flex; white-space: normal;">
      <img src="~/Images/Logo_Circle.png" alt="RCA" width="80" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server" />
       <span style="font-size:25px;color:white;"><span style="color:#e4b16d">City  of Testing</span><br />This is the company name</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </nav>

   <div style="background-color:white;border-radius:10px;align-content:center;align-self:center;vertical-align:middle;width:100%" class="container max-width-940 body-content">
      <div style="margin-top: 0px">

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel2" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
            <div style="align-items:center; justify-content:left;display:flex;font-size:24px"><b>Recording test testing</b></div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div>
              <span style="font-size:18px"> This is a test1. This is a test2.This is a test3.This is a test4.This is a test5.This is a test6.This is a test7.This is a test8.This is a test9.This is a test10.This is a test11This is a test12This is a test13This is a test14This is a test15This is a test16This is a test17This is a test18This is a test19This is a test20This is a test21This is a test22This is a test23This is a test24.</span>
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>

          </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
      </div>
    </div>
```

below is the screen shot:

[image]

and somehow when I resize the screen my navigation bar starts overlapping the conetent of the screen. How can I fix this overlapping and text coming beyond the scren when resizing.

Comment: Looks like your `min-width` you set on the default class is perhaps meant to be `max-width` ? However if you actually want responsive design, why not use the built grid and utility classes bootstrap provides for these kinds of scenarios for a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to make the bootstrap container bigger (the width) is the following:

```
@media (min-width: 1440px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1240px !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1640px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1440px !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1840px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1640px !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 2040px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1840px  !important;
    }
}

$container-max-widths: (
    sm: 700px,
    md: 800px,
    lg: 960px,
    xl: 1140px
) !default;

$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 576px,
    md: 768px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1400px,
    xxl: 2000px
);
```

The min-width you're using doesn't work because bootstrap is working with max-width.

Comment: This works! except my navbar is still overlapping the content of the page. any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Put padding on the section/ div that has the overlap. If the overlap is on the top: padding: 40px 0;

On the side: padding: 0 40px;

Comment: padding is not working. I will post this question separately..